# I'm going insane! "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server."

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

ok I am new to this but I have spent a week literally trying to resolve this issue trying all the advice on here and nothing works. I've been playing with alot of different things.

I have installed:
W10
Wampserver V2.5
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.12
MySQL 5.6.17
My HTTPD config contains:

```
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny,allow
    Require all denied
    Deny from all
#    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

...

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
#     Order Deny,Allow
#    Deny from all
     Require all denied
     Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
     Require local
#    Require all granted
```

In my browser (Chrome) I can use localhost and 127.0.0.1 and view the Wampserver page.

In my phpmyadmin.conf I have

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from ::1 127.0.0.1 localhost
#         Allow from all
    </IfDefine>
```

Which is basically as it was installed.

When I try to access the phpmyadmin I get the Forbidden message and in the error log I see:

```
[Thu Sep 29 19:50:34.468850 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 224:tid 1124] [client ::1:63590] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/, referer: http://localhost/
```

In my alias for phpmyadmin it states:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
#     Deny from all
      Allow from ::1 127.0.0.1 localhost
#         Allow from all
    </IfDefine>
```

I can access via chrome:

http://localhost/?phpinfo=1

BUT
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

is Forbidden

For my sanity I hope someone can assist,

Dan.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the newer WAMPServer 3?

Comment: Apart from the fact I did not know it existed no :) I'll download it when I get home and see if that helps. I assume I can just download it over the top of my current version.

Comment: Ah, nothing is ever simple - I've just read I cannot install over my existing Winamp :)

Comment: I followed the instructions here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606 Then with the help of here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295 I installed WAMPServer3 and it worked out the box.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606

Then with the help of here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295 I installed WAMPServer3.

Works out the box.

I did have to find VS 2013 / 2015 and install them, I did change SKype and I ran as admin.

Thanks.